# how to print a condition at last after executing all the if else code

Tags: c, if-statement, cs50

I want to check the input if the input is in the **string names** then print the number of the
given name. If the given name is not in the **string names** then print "your name is not here" but I'm getting "your name is not here" every time I run my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
string userinput;
string names [] = {"david", "mark"};
string numbers[] = {"123456789","987654321"};
userinput = get_string("name: ");

for(int i = 0; i<2 ;i++)
{
    if(strcmp(names[i], userinput) == 0)
    {
        printf("your number is %s ", numbers[i]);
    }
}
printf("your name is not here\n");
}




 **ACTUAL OUTPUT**

 name: david
 your number is 123456789 your name is not here
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, but `printf("your name is not here\n");` will execute no matter what the input is. Could it be that you wanted to use an `if-else` statement instead?

Comment: You need a flag variable (of type `bool`) you set to true when you find the name in the list. After the loop, if that flag is false, it means the name wasn't found, and you print the "your name is not here" message

Comment: Why would you expect anything other than what you see? That last `printf` isn't in any sort of conditional block, nor even inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution would be creating a variable to keep track if the name has been found:

```c
int found = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<2 ;i++)
{
    if(strcmp(names[i], userinput) == 0)
    {
        printf("your number is %s ", numbers[i]);
        found = 1;
        // Break so we don't have to iterate over the rest
        // of the items if we already found our name.
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) printf("your name is not here\n");
```

Comment: While we are at it, a `break` statement would be a great addition.

Comment: @ypnos Yep, you're right. Added it, thanks!

Comment: @ypnos hello, could you tell that how do the found variable works? and also what does this "!" operator does in (!found)".

Answer (score 0):

This is naturally very simple code, but you should already start to think about program design early on. Your code does three different, separate things:

1. Prompt for input/take user input (I/O).
2. Search if input matches a value (search algorithm).
3. Present the results (I/O).

Ideally keep parts 2) and 3) separate not to mix up I/O with algorithms, so:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
...

bool found = false;
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
  if(strcmp(names[i], userinput) == 0)
  {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(found)
{
  printf("your number is %s \n", numbers[i]);
}
else
{
  printf("your name is not here\n");
}
```

We could split up these parts in separate functions if we wish. For example if the amount of strings is expanded, we'll want to implement a better search algorithm than this "brute force" loop.